# android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner how to change TextColor/Style

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-styles, android-appcompat

I did search for info but no styling option works for me.
I want just to change the TextColor of the AppCompatSpinner.

---

Using

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

How can I overwrite the textColor attribute using style?
`AppCompatSpinner` is not convenient.

Answer (score -3):

Use custom spinner for this and put a textview in your spinner and use TextView's id while spinner.setAdapter() method :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"  
    android:textColor="#FF0000"         
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

use adapter to show the spinner :-

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,R.id.textview,list);
```